# How to post json data with extJS

Tags: html, json, post, extjs

I'm a bit of a newb with both extJS and json. What is the most painless route to POSTing json data using extJS? I'm not really interested any GUI features, just using the framework to send some sample data.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'foo.php',    // where you wanna post
   success: passFn,   // function called on success
   failure: failFn,
   params: { foo: 'bar' }  // your json data
});
```

Comment: This will post URLencoded like data... IOW, the POST buffer will be foo=bar. If you replace the `params` for `jsonData` it will post raw JSON, so the POST buffer will be `{"foo":"bar"}`

Comment: In ExtJS 4.1 you can use the jsonData Member.

Answer (score 20):

The following will identify as '**POST**' request

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'foo.php',    // where you wanna post
       success: passFn,   // function called on success
       failure: failFn,
       jsonData: { foo: 'bar' }  // your json data
    });
```

The following will identify as '**GET**' request

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'foo.php',    // where you wanna make the get request
   success: passFn,   // function called on success
   failure: failFn,
   params: { foo: 'bar' }  // your json data
});
```

Comment: you can also use `method: 'POST' / 'GET'` parameter: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-property-method

Answer (score 6):

Just to add my two cents:

```
//
//Encoding to JSON:
//
var myObj = {
  visit: "http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com/"
};
var jsonStr = Ext.encode(myObj);


//
// Decoding from JSON
//
var myObjCopy = Ext.decode(jsonStr);
document.location.href = myObj.visit;
```

Answer (score 3):

The examples posted here show the basic idea. For complete details on all configurable options see the [Ext.Ajax docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax).

Comment: Link is broken, have to navigate to the EXT.Ajax section

Answer (score 0):

Code Snippet:

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
    success: function (response) {
        Ext.Msg.alert("success", response.responseText);
    },
    failure: function () {
        Ext.Msg.alert("failure", "failed to load")
    },
    params: {
        "name": "morpheus",
        "job": "leader"
    }
});
```

Fiddle:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28h1