# Post Raw Json via .submit()

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I post username/password as Raw JSON via form.submit().

```
loginForm.submit({  
    url: 'localhost/login',
    method: 'post',
    jsonData: loginForm.getValues()
...
    success: ...
```

even with `Ext.JSON.encode(loginForm.getValues())` server is receiving as username=test&password=test which I need to be {"username":"test","password":"test"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably try something like

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'submit.php',
    params  : {
        data: Ext.encode(loginForm.getValues())
    },
    success: function() {
    },
    failure: function() {
    }
});
```

[Source for reference](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?243325-How-to-ExtJS-4.x-to-submit-a-post-with-json-payload-and-return-a-pdf)

Comment: Yeah this might work, but since there are bad api design, which I dont have access to them, I have to post exactly as {"username":"test","password":"test"}. adding data: {"username":"test","password":"test"} wont work.

Comment: i see, have you looked at this other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917581/how-to-post-json-data-with-extjs)?

Comment: Yeah, I searched every thing that google can find, it is posting like url-form-encoded params, username=test&password=test which is causing Error 500 on server.  I was able to post JSON with php and chrome rest client.

Comment: I didnt see Ext.Ajax.request({ on your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case with ExtJS, there's an easy answer. In the config of the loginForm:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
   title: 'Simple Form',

  // The form will submit an AJAX request to this URL when submitted
  url: 'save-form.php',

  .... (blah blah blah)

  jsonSubmit: true    // <---- set this to TRUE
});
```

Set the property **`jsonSubmit: true`**. 
Then when you use `loginForm.submit()`, your object will be submitted as JSON rather than form params.

Here's a link to the form docs:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel

Answer (score 0):

> When a form is submitted, it is not submitted in JSON format.
>   In order to submit JSON string, Ext.Ajax.request must be used.
>   http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132082-jsonData-in-submit-action-of-form

I just had to change

```
loginForm.submit({})
```

to

```
Ext.Ajax.request({})
```

and use

`params: Ext.JSON.encode(loginForm.getValues()),`

Bad DOCS.

Comment: I think the docs are pretty extensive. One of the most extensive online documents for any framework. Yes, certain implementation and design alternatives are not mentioned but that's for us to apply.