# Form submission (POST): Add get parameter

Tags: extjs, extjs6

How can I define additional url parameters for my POST form submission?

This is how I load my form:

```
form.load({
    url:APIURI+'GetComment',
    method:'GET',
    params:params,
});
```

Result: The params object is serialized into GET parameters; the form content is returned as JSON.

This is how I submit my form:

```
form.submit({
    url:APIURI+'SetComment',
    method:'POST',
    params:params,
    callback:function() {
        me.close();
    }
});
```

Expected result: The form data should be sent as JSON POSTDATA, and the params should be sent as GET parameters.

Actual result: The form data was made an object; then the params were applied to that very object - and some of them overrode form fields which go by the same name.

What I also tried: I tried to put the params into the options object as `urlParams`, `baseParams` and `extraParams`, but none of these work.

Comment: Maybe try using `Ext.Ajax.request()`. Similar like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917581/how-to-post-json-data-with-extjs) question.

Comment: @BojanDević Well, that does not help with submission of the form. I would have to manually collect the form data form submission then, manually validate it and so on...

Comment: but thats just `form.isValid()` and `form.getValues()`.

Comment: You could serialize params and append the string to the url, for example: `Ext.Object.toQueryString(params)`

Comment: @tonymayoral Digging through the `form.submit()` code, I found no possibility to inject parameters into the url. So I guess your proposed way is the only feasible one. Please make it an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could serialize params and append the string to the url, such as:

```
form.submit({
  url: APIURI + 'SetComment?' + Ext.Object.toQueryString(params),
  method: 'POST',
  callback: function() {
    me.close();
  }
});
```